# How can I choose the whole string if there's no number after any math operator with JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

So I've tried my best with this one:

`/\d+([+-/*.])\d{0}/g`

Hoping it to match with **for example 55-** (But when there's no number after any math operator)
but it matched with **55-** *even though there is some number after the operator.* (**for example:  55-5** It chose the first three characters but as you can see there's "5" after it.)

If you can help I appreciate it!

*Also this is my first question on stackoverflow.*

Comment: So you want the string `"55-"` to match but not `"55-5"`?

Comment: yes i want the string **55-** when there's no number after any math operators like choose **55-** but don't choose it when there is some number like 55-5. Mine chooses 55- even though there's 5 after the minus

Comment: `/\d+[+-/*.](?=\D|$)/g`

Comment: Actually, `\d+[+-/*.](?!\d)` works too and it marginally more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{0}` doesn't mean "There should be exactly 0 after this", per regex101

> {0} matches the previous token exactly zero times (causes token to be ignored)

You also forgot to escape the `-` and `\` in your `[  ]` section.

This is your original regex: https://regex101.com/r/JGnJe7/1/

Use this regex for the whole string `/^\d+([+\-\/*.])$/`.

```js
const matchString = str => str.match(/^\d+([+\-\/*.])$/);

const fiftyfivedash = "55-";
const fiftyfivedashfive = "55-5";

console.log(matchString(fiftyfivedash));
console.log(matchString(fiftyfivedashfive));
```

`/^\d+([+\-\/*.])$/` means: https://regex101.com/r/SDrDJx/1

- Match must start at index 0 (`^`)
- One or more numbers
- One of the symbols
- Match must end at the last index (`$`)

Some alternatives if you don't want the whole string:

```js
const matchString = str => str.match(/\d+[+\-\/*.](?!\d)/g);
const matchStringOther = str => str.match(/\d+[+\-\/*.](?=\D|$)/g);

const fiftyfivedash = "hello 55- 4+ 66*";
const fiftyfivedashfive = "55-5  45-2 456+2";

console.log(matchString(fiftyfivedash));
console.log(matchString(fiftyfivedashfive));

console.log(matchStringOther(fiftyfivedash));
console.log(matchStringOther(fiftyfivedashfive));
```

`/\d+[+\-\/*.](?!\d)/g` means: https://regex101.com/r/sDgGTV/1

- One or more numbers
- One of the symbols
- Noncapturing (the `?`), anything except (the `!`): a number
- Search multiple times and return all matches (the `g`)

`/\d+[+\-\/*.](?=\D|$)/g` means: https://regex101.com/r/HZayTg/1

- One or more numbers
- One of the symbols
- Noncapturing (the `?`), either the next character is not a number, or there is no more characters (the `$` means end of string)
- Search multiple times and return all matches (the `g`)

Comment: Thank you, this helps too.